# regex to obtain text between several html tags

Tags: regex

From the book Oreilly Mastering Regular Expressions, I found out this example:

to take only text from `<a href="http://www.oreilly.com">O’Reilly Media</a>`

he proposed to use the regex like this `<a\b([ˆ>]+)>(.+?)</a>`

But for me no luck to catch only text.

Please, could enyone explain to me how build regex to catch only text.

I try to understand regex, so please, be polite, don't tell me to use another methods to parse html.

Thank you.

Comment: Replace `ˆ` with `^`.

Comment: If I do so, regex catch all.

Comment: Matches all and captures two chunks. The second contains the string you want.

Comment: What do you mean? [Look at the demo](https://regex101.com/r/cdIw7h/1), suit yourself and pick any group from the 3 (Group 0, 1 and 2)

Comment: ok, this work and now I read your demo to understand. Thank you.

Comment: Just a note: understanding regex includes understanding when to use it and when to refrain from using it. There are types of text data that is not really supposed to be parsed with regex.

Comment: Feel free to use regex to strip markup tags, it's great for that !!

Answer (score 0):

To reveal all the text between tags, strip off the tags.

`<(?:(?:(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*(?=>))|(?:/?[\w:]+\s*/?)|(?:[\w:]+\s+(?:"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|[^>]?)+\s*/?)|\?[\S\s]*?\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\S\s]*?)|(?:\[CDATA\[[\S\s]*?\]\])|(?:--[\S\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\S\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\S\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\S\s]*?))))>`

https://regex101.com/r/B4Dhkj/1